# tensorflow Asymmetric loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

I want to implement an asymmetric loss function such as referenced here

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37955/how-to-design-and-implement-an-asymmetric-loss-function-for-regression

in TensorFlow.

I currently am using the mean square error loss function:

mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(out,Y))

Which I want to replace with 
mse = tf.reduce_mean(asymetric_squared_difference(out,Y,alpha))

I Looked to see where tf.squared_difference is defined, and found https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squared_difference 
Which says that tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py

edit: 
After much digging SquaredDifference is called from ops.math_grad line 999 to 1012.  But it has a lot of extra gradiant functionality that I am not sure how to replicate.

How would I best go about adding this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to implement your own, or would you rather just use any of the asymmetric functions (which should be able to be used as loss functions, as a 'loss' function is just a label for a function used to control loss)

Most of the functions on here that are asymmetric, should be compatible.

Off the top, you could just use

```
tf.zeta(x,q)
```

in place of

```
tf.squared_difference(x,y)
```

to replace your symmetric loss function (tf.squared_difference) with an asymmetric one (tf.zeta).

If you still want to implement a loss function, then you'd have to define the operation over two `Tensor`s (while also observing the unlisted `name` function parameter I've left out) and return the result, [just like tf.zeta does](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeta).

Also, you should check out the ["Forecasting unemployment rate. . ." paper](https://editorialexpress.com/cgi-bin/conference/download.cgi?db_name=ESAM09&paper_id=194) that speaks to your needs, as highlighted in [your link to the "Cross validated" stack exchange post that sent you on your journey](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37955/how-to-design-and-implement-an-asymmetric-loss-function-for-regression) :)  It contains the equation for the basic expression an asymmetric loss function needs, which is what I used to search for `tf.zeta` in the TensorFlow docs for ["Basic Math Functions"](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/math_ops#Basic_Math_Functions).

But I could be totally wrong. I don't know.  I don't use TensorFlow. . .yet.

Comment: I would be happy to use any pre-existing function that takes two vectors X and Y and returns some product of their difference which is smoothly increasing as X and Y  get further apart and which results in a bigger increase when Y > X then it does when X>Y by the same amount. 


Looking at the tf.zeta(x,q) function it doesn't appear to do that. also it might be the case that zeta is divergent for Re(x)~=1 which could be a problem.

Comment: Got it.  I didn't know you had specific requirements, but I would recommend just thinking about any mathematical function you already know that does that, and see if tf.whatever doesn't exist for it :)  If not, then you'd be stuck implementing it.  You'd also have to start at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc to define your function, and then figure out where the implementation part is defined ( I only did a search for 'zeta' and found these defines).

Comment: on second thought, it sounds like tf.pow(x, y) would work. . .

Comment: I couldn't get Pow to take into account the difference between the two vectors.  It is wonderfully asymmetric but I couldn't coheres it to operate on the residual.

Comment: how so (with respect to the residual)?  The residual, with pow, would actually need another call to pow with the operands reverse, and then have the difference between x^y and y^x in order to seek how they diverge, no?  Unless I'm just thinking wrongly.  It'd look an awfully lot like squared difference at that point, so I just tend to do stuff like use the ratio that results from multiplying 1/y by x^y. . . YMMV, and I am only speaking to getting assymetric losses, which can be built any which way you desire.  However, I acknowledge that it is a bit more cumbersome to match it to tf's API